# ASP .NET Core MVC deploy to azure Identity Server 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, identityserver4

I have identity server deploy in azure, when i try deploy my MVC asp .net core as a client. unathorized client error showing up. whats wrong with my config below ?

**StartUp Client MVC**

```
 JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
            services.AddAuthentication(options => {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
            .AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options => {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                options.Authority = Configuration.GetValue<string>("server:identityurl");
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ClientId = Configuration.GetValue<string>("server:clientid");
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration.GetValue<string>("server:clientsecret");
                options.ResponseType = Configuration.GetValue<string>("server:responsetype");

                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                options.Scope.Add(Configuration.GetValue<string>("server:scope1"));
                options.Scope.Add(Configuration.GetValue<string>("server:scope2"));
            });
```

**Appsetting.json & Appsetting.Development.Json**

```
"server": {
        "identityurl": "https://pdjayaauthapi.azurewebsites.net",
        "clientid": "webapp2",
        "clientsecret": "web123",
        "responsetype": "code id_token",
        "scope1": "masterdataapi",
        "scope2": "offline_access"
    }
```

**Identity Server startup**

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var sqlConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySqlCon");

            services.AddDbContext<PDJayaDB>(options =>
                options.UseMySql(
                    sqlConnectionString,
                    b => b.MigrationsAssembly("PDJaya.Identity")
                )
            );
            //my user repository
            services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();


            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
            services.AddMvc();
            // configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and resources
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
                .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers())
                .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();
            //Inject the classes we just created
            services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
            services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();

        }
```

and this is my identityserver config to define client asp .net mvc.

**Identity Server Config**

new Client

```
                ClientId = "webapp2", 
                ClientName = "web with openid",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,

                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("web123".Sha256())
                },

                RedirectUris           = { "http://pdjayaauthapi.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://pdjayaauthapi.azurewebsites.net/signout-callback-oidc" },

                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "masterdataapi",
                    "transactionapi"
                },
                AllowOfflineAccess = true
```

Comment: Identity server log will have the reason. Look at that or post the log for further help

Comment: may you teach me about how to see the log? my identity server running on azure as a app service.@Richard

Comment: If you are using the "code id_token" response type, try setting the Client to use the Hybrid flow instead of the Implicit flow that is set.

Comment: i change to Hybridandclientcredential and, my error invalid request now, any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Hybrid flow instead of the Implicit flow that is set as Ryan said. And restart the web app. It should fix the error.